# Imperfections in Eevee animation render

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine, linux

I am working on making animations for molecular orbitals using Blender for Linux 2.83.0 (I render on a farm). I import two OpenVDB files, apply some volume nodes on them to give them the correct density and colour, and then I start rendering an animation using a camera turning around the volumes, following a path. I use Eevee for rendering. When rendered and put together via FFmpeg, the animation shows some frames with some kind of white, grey or black square on it, making it look like a 60s movie because it resembles some broken parts on the film. First I thought the problem would be in FFmpeg, but after looking at the individual frames, I learned that it was already present there:

[image: 0068.png]
[image: 0103.png]
[image: 0140.png]

Does anyone know where this is coming from and (even more important) how to fix this? I already tried cranking up the sampling size (from 64 to 128), but this did not work.
Thanks in advance!

ADDED AFTER 2 HOURS:
I tried recreating the error on my own (Windows) system (2.83.1), and the problem does not occur. So, the problem lies most likely in the Linux version.

ADDED AFTER 12 HOURS:
We updated the Linux version of Blender to 2.83.3, but this did not improve it.

Comment: If a problem occurs in Linux but not Windows, you should probably suspect your video card drivers.  If that's the source of the problem, the only fix is to use Windows to render instead.  Any time that Windows and Linux disagree on a render, it's totally appropriate to submit a bug report.

Comment: I agree with Nathan, but also the current 2.83 LTS version of Blender for both Linux and Windows and available [here](https://www.blender.org/download/lts/2-83/) is 2.83.16 so I'm not sure where you're downloading them from? - Just noticed when this question was first asked which answers that one!

Comment: It will be interesting to see if the problem is still occurring with more recent versions.